# gh api pass array field

Tags: github-api, github-cli

I am trying to use `gh api --method PUT orgs/<ORG>/actions/permissions/selected-actions` that accepts 3 fields: one of them `patterns_allowed`. I have tried multiple ways to pass the data, but I always get

```
{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\nFor 'properties/patterns_allowed', \"...\" is not an array.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#set-allowed-actions-for-an-organization"
}
```

One of this attempts looks like this:

```
ALLOWED="foo,bar"
gh api --method PUT \
    orgs/${{github.repository_owner}}/actions/permissions/selected-actions \
    --field "github_owned_allowed=true" \
    --field "verified_allowed=false" \
    --field "patterns_allowed=[$ALLOWED]"
```

What is the proper way to pass array type field?

Comment: Can you show how you're passing that data now?

Comment: @wkl done, added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gh api --field` doesn't accept JSON arrays, it's an open issue for the project as [cli/cli issue #1484](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1484).

What you'd have to do instead is provide the JSON payload by specifying it directly as `--input`, so you have to create the JSON separate from the command, like in the following where I'm creating it as a heredoc string and then piping it into the `gh api` command:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# This needs to be quoted correctly for substituting
# as the elements of a JSON list
ALLOWED='"foo","bar"'

# Using a heredoc to make our JSON payload
read -r -d '' PAYLOAD <<-JSON
{
    "github_owned_allowed": true,
    "verified_allowed": false,
    "patterns_allowed": [${ALLOWED}]
}
JSON

echo "$PAYLOAD" | gh api --method PUT \
    orgs/YOUR_ORG/actions/permissions/selected-actions \
    --input -
```

This could be made slightly less clunky if you have `jq`, but I assumed no extra tools on your part.

Comment: took some tinkering, but now I have it working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Check if [gh 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.21.0) would help: [PR 6614](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6614) does fix [issue 1484](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1484)

```bash
gh api -f labels[]=bug -f labels[]=p1
#=> { "labels": ["bug", "p1"] }

gh api -f branch[name]=patch-1 -F branch[protected]=true
#=> { "branch": { "name": "patch-1", "protected": true }
```

In your case:

```bash
ALLOWED=("foo" "bar")
gh api --method PUT \
    orgs/${{github.repository_owner}}/actions/permissions/selected-actions \
    --field "github_owned_allowed=true" \
    --field "verified_allowed=false" \
    --field "patterns_allowed[]=${ALLOWED[0]}" \
    --field "patterns_allowed[]=${ALLOWED[1]}"
```

Comment: Wow that is not obvious! And not mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/rest/teams/teams#create-a-team) i.e. `repo_names array of strings
The full name (e.g., "organization-name/repository-name") of repositories to add the team to.`